# Cannot get a switch listener working with setOnCheckedChange(onCheckedChange)

Tags: android

I'm having a problem having a switch button listener to work correctly. It is in my main activity as is:

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

    private Switch mySwitch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled();

        // React to settings change
        mySwitch= findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this); // <--------
    }

    public void onCheckedChange(CompoundButton s, boolean isChecked) {
        ...
    }

}
```

At the arrow line, I tried with this (like a sample on the internet). It is marked in Android Studio as an error. AS suggests me to cast to a CommpoundButton.onCheckedChange (or similar). When I start the app, it crashs saying MainActivity cannot be casted to that. I cannot do also setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChange);

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `@Override` notation? And does your WearableActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `OnCheckedChangeListener` if you want to use `this` as a option for `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
```

This is because `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` will only accept an instance of `OnCheckedChangeListener`, so you can't simply use `this` since the Activity that `this` is pointing to isn't an instance of `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

However, since `OnCheckedChangeListener` is an interface, this is easily rectified by implementing `OnCheckedChangeListener`. Thanks to how inheritance works in Java, Activity automatically becomes an instance of `OnCheckedChangeListener` once the interface has been implemented.

It looks like this was the option you were going for since you're also overriding the `onCheckedChange()` method inside your Activity.

Comment: Ohhh, that was the second suggestion from Android Studio... I feel stupid now!

Comment: Hi Maxim, you may want to mark @jackey's answer as accepted if it solved your issue so that he'll get his deserved points for it. This is a good way to say thanks and a good incentive for people to keep helping others here on SO. :)

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos yes I had to wait several minutes before accepting, then I forgot.